# Queries Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How I do this select in Rails?

```
SELECT Women.phone, Users.name FROM women, users  WHERE (users.cellid = women.cell_id);
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cellid, :name
    belongs_to :woman
end
```

model/woman.rb

```
class Woman < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cell_id, :phone
    has_many :users
end
```

controller/index.rb

```
def index
  @variables = User.all
  @phones = Woman.all
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement implies that `User` and `Woman` are linked by the fields cellid and cell_id, so you have to specify those in your `belongs_to` and `has_many` directives:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cellid, :name
  belongs_to :woman, foreign_key: :cellid, primary_key: :cell_id
end

class Woman < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cell_id, :phone
  has_many :users, foreign_key: :cellid, primary_kay: :cell_id
end
```

While this is possible, it's always better to use Rails conventions and use `:id` as primary key and `woman_id` as foreign key, if possible.

Then in you controller you can do something like:

```
@users= User.all
```

and in your view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %> has woman with phone <%= user.woman.phone %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways you can do this (I'd go with the second option):

```
# First option
User.find_by_sql('select Women.phone, Users.name from Women, Users where Users.cellid = Women.cell_id')

# Second option
User.joins(:women).where('Users.cellid = Women.cell_id').select(['Women.phone', 'Users.name'])
```

In both cases you will get array of `Users` object which will contain `Women.phone` and `Users.name` attributes.

Comment: you second option implies that `users` and `women` are joined the normal rails way via id. I can't see this in Oleg's example SQL.

Comment: @MartinM, you are right, they are joined the normal rails way via `id`; anything wrong with that?  I posted that option because I prefer that method over writing query as in first option.

Comment: your answer is all right, I just wanted to point out for others, that the sql snipets in the example are not reflecting the normal rails way.